# Multiple possible text inputs with if statements

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to make a fully immersive text adventure using a batch file.

Here is my problem: I want the answers to be a text input, so that the players type in a response which dictates where they will go.

For a lot of questions I need there to be multiple possible inputs. For example when you get to an enemy there are tons of different things you could do, however I can only figure out how to get it to recognise one input.

With other words, I want system to take user input and do actions accordingly.

Here is my code for this section so far:

```
:forest1

echo you awake in a forest, you do not know where you are or why you are there.

echo infront of you is a small goblin like creature

:recoil1

echo What do you do?

set /p answer=

if %answer%==run (

goto run1

) else (

if %answer%==attack (

goto attack1

) else ( 

if %answer%==befriend(

goto befriend1

) else (

if %answer%==scream(

goto scream1

) else ( 

if %answer%==dance (

goto dance1

) else (

echo Nothing happened

timeout /t 1

goto forest1

)
```

Comment: Use the `Choice` command and provide only the options for which you have possible actions. Type `Choice /?` at the Command Prompt for its usage information.

Comment: i had a look at this, is there any way to do it so that the user doesn't know the different options

Comment: I'd quote both sides of `==` and add `/I`, so `if /I "%answer%"=="run". Sometimes the space in front of `(` is missing. But the main problem is that you have numerous unbalanced parentheses...

Answer (score 1):

Your way should be modified like this to work:

```bat
@echo off

rem Your code before the code you provided above ^^

:forest1
echo You awake in a forest, you do not know where you are or why you are there.
echo In front of you is a small goblin like creature
goto :recoil1

:recoil1
set /p "answer=What do you do? "
if "%answer%" == "run" (
    goto :run1
) else (
    if "%answer%" == "attack" (
        goto :attack1
    ) else ( 
        if "%answer%" == "befriend" (
            goto :befriend1
        ) else (
            if "%answer%" == "scream" (
                goto :scream1
            ) else ( 
                if "%answer%" == "dance" (
                    goto :dance1
                ) else (
                    echo Nothing happened.
                    timeout /t 1
                    goto :forest1
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You see: this is complicated a bit; you missed lots of parenthesis!

So, use `choice` command with some modifications:

```bat
@echo off

rem Your code before the code you provided above ^^

:forest1
echo You awake in a forest, you do not know where you are or why you are there.
echo In front of you is a small goblin like creature
goto :recoil1

:recoil1
echo What do you do? Here is a list of options:
echo r - run away
echo a - attack the goblin
echo b - be friend with the goblin
echo s - scream
echo d - dance
echo n - do nothing

choice /C:rabsdn /N

if errorlevel 6 (
    echo Nothing happened.
    timeout /t 1
    goto :forest1
)
if errorlevel 5 goto :dance1
if errorlevel 4 goto :scream1
if errorlevel 3 goto :befriend1
if errorlevel 2 goto :attack1
if errorlevel 1 goto :run1
```

which is clearer, faster and more readable, isn't it?

Note: the `if` with the `errorlevel` should be in descending order because `if errorlevel n` means if the `errorlevel` is ***greater than or equal*** to `n`!

Modify the options to better suit for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try use **`if`** in the **`for`** looping to do this job?

```bat
@echo off
:forest1
cls & echo/ & if defined answer set answer=<nul
echo/  you awake in a forest, you do not know where you are or why you are there.
echo/  infront of you is a small goblin like creature

:recoil1
set /p "answer= What do you do? "
for %%i in (run attack befriend scream dance) do if /i "%answer%" == "%%i" goto :%answer%1

echo/ Nothing happened
timeout /t 1 & goto forest1

:run1 
echo/ Here I'm in Label run1 & exit /b

:attack1
echo/ Here I'm in Label attack1 & exit /b

:befriend1 
echo/ Here I'm in Label befriend1 & exit /b

:scream1 
echo/ Here I'm in Label scream1 & exit /b

:dance1
echo/ Here I'm in Label dance1 & exit /b
```